# Pin a managed List<> to get a pointer to the data

Tags: c#, unmanaged, managed, unsafe, pinning

I need to quickly pass data in a generic .net list to unmanaged code, and since a list is internally an array, I wanted to pin it and get a pointer to the data, but a basic pinning doesnt seem to point to the data, but rather to the object itself.

How do you get native access to the data containing array for a List declared and filled in c#?

Comment: What is this a list of? Bytes?

Comment: `List<T>` is not an array by itself. It wraps an array; but that is an implementation detail which you shouldn't rely on. That said; you can use reflection to get the reference to internal array and pin it. If array was resized later(due to adding elements), pinning will have no effect because you've pinned a different array.

Comment: You have a point in that the external interface of List doesn't demand it to have an internal array, so that could change. I would still be interested in seeing an example of using reflection to get to the internals and pin it. Can you help with that?

Answer (score 2):

Use the ToArray function and then pin the resulting array. Below is the source to ToArray which is fast.

```
public T[] ToArray()
{
    T[] array = new T[_size];
    Array.Copy(_items, 0, array, 0, _size);
    return array;
}
```

In the technical sense you could use reflection to get the list's _items member then pin it, but...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as far as I know, ToArray will actually allocate an array on heap and then do a copy from the array inside the list to the new array. This will, I would assume, not happen element by element, but by a single memcopy call, but I would still hope to find a way to avoid this extra allocation and copy, by simply accessing the memory inside the list.

Comment: Unless you are dealing with an extremely large array the cost of making a second copy which is an allocation and a memory copy is going to way out perform using reflection to access the List's internal variables.  There are ways to do a one time look up but is it worth the extra complexity and risks?